# Ant: How do you get it to print out your errors nicely?

Tags: ant, build, warnings

Whenever I run ant to build a huge project, my error messages get swamped in a huge pile of warnings instead. How do I make it so that ant doesn't print all these warnings, or at least print the errors at the end of its build output (or some other method that allows for convenient reading of the errors?)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [ANT build listeners and loggers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html).

For example:

```
ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.XmlLogger clean build
```

Generates an XML file that can be transformed, using XSLT, into a HTML file. This makes log viewing more pleasant:

```
xsltproc $ANT_HOME/etc/log.xsl log.xml > log.html
```